# Bloomberg Ticker mapping with Reuters RIC

Tags: market-data, bloomberg, reuters

I am trying to map Bloomberg ticker into Reuters one.
For example this one: `EDZ3C 96.625 COMDT`

Few years ago aforementioned BBG ticker would be mapped to Reuters RIC: `GE96625L3`

This can be decoded as:

- `GE`: code for **Globex Exchange**
- `96625`: the strike **96.625**
- `L`: calculated based on rule: A-L (call) and M-X (put) where A, M=Jan; B, N=Feb; ….; L, X=Dec, meaning that our option has:

  - Expiry: **December**
  - Type: **Call**
- `3`: Expiry year (**2023**)

How do I find Reuters RIC pattern nowadays? This is a question about listed options data.

Comment: It's not Reuters anymore :) it got spun off to Refinitive, then LSE bought Refinitive.. as of this writing no one bought LSE. Anyway this page https://developers.refinitiv.com/datascope-select-dss/datascope-select-rest-api/learning?content=11081&type=learning_material_item suggests that you should use the API (passing underlying RIC, strike, and expiry) to search for the listed option's RIC, and not assume a pattern and not construct it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Is this a generic question or specific to Eurodollar options?

And I note that "Z3" will now return Dec '23, not Dec '13.

EDIT: In Reuters (technically Eikon from Refinitiv) you can map from ISIN to RIC. If you can find a way to map from Bloomberg ticker to ISIN first, then you can do this via two stages. No idea if that's possible but seems like it's worth checking.

Comment: right, Z3 would be Dec '23 nowadays.
It is specific to Eurodollar.

Comment: The month code Z is not specific to Eurodollars nor is the 2023 expiration (e.g. dividend futures or crude oil futures, to name just two, extend out that far).

Comment: The 3 is not totally generic, some underlyings (ie natgas) use 2 digit year codes, on both bbg and reuters. Though be advised that the spreads in bbg switch back to single digits (they don't on reuters though).

Answer (score 0):

Option mapping RIC to Bloomberg or vice versa is one of the trickiest tasks

In theory with the RIC root, BBG root, Strike, Exercise style, Put Call Indicator, expiry date, exchange MIC it is possible create a RIC code ( and indeed this is how Magtia does exactly that). However not all the meta data required can be parsed from the BBG symbol, you need access to the fields stated above .

Even then you will need to know "how to scale the Strike in the RIC"  A strike of 15.5 can be represented by 0155 15500 01550 any number of ways. And it gets worse the scaling can alter as you transition from 99-100 (common in options on bond futures). Other series may have both 100 and 100 strikes, map these wrong and your trading the wrong instrument e.g the S&P500 mini strikes range from 10000 to 520000

At Magtia we have to create large tables of meta data to handle all the rules and exceptions  see [www.magtia.com](http://www.magtia.com)

Answer (score 0):

Just use [www.magtia.com](http://www.magtia.com) services.

I realize it's a very simplistic answer. However, you either want to be in the mapping business forever and spend 1.5 full time analysts doing this right, or, naturally, outsource this activity to Magtia.

It's a business solution, not a mapping solution.

If business requirements are relaxed and you can afford mistakes, unmapped contracts which will still require investigation and manual intervention (i.e. someone's time), then come up with heuristics.